# Abstract Factory: are constructors with parameters allowed in concrete product classes?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

In the abstract factory pattern, the concrete product created by a concrete factory implements a certain interface. Are there other constraints in the implementation of concrete products? For example, are not-default constructors allowed in concrete product classes?

Example:

```
public class XmlDaoFactory : DaoFactory
{
    public override ICustomersDao CreateCustomersDao()
    {
        // XmlCustomersDao is a concrete product
        return new XmlCustomersDao(1000, true);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, are not-default constructors allowed in concrete product classes?

Sure.  That's the beauty of using an AbstractFactory; these details can be hidden in your concrete factory without the client having to be aware of them.

Comment: Could the parameters be loaded from a configuration file?

Comment: What is Mars? What is the purpose of Mars?